# Saving Euro currency value in database

Tags: sql-server

I want to store euro value as in format like  12.230,30 in database .If anyone have solution please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your concrete problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't save formatted data. Save the value, format on display.

Comment: There's more to it than just saving the value.  Some decimal values cannot be saved precisely and when imprecise monetary values are added, the result can become even more imprecise.  "Money" has to be stored so that the minimum monetary unit -- a "cent", for example -- can be represented without any loss of accuracy.

Comment: @julie: no, decimal values CAN be saved exactly. that's the whole point of the DECIMAL type. You're thinking of float/real values. Those can't be stored exactly.

Comment: @MarcB: Yes, for databases which support the DECIMAL type with fixed point precision, that would be the correct type to use.  However, not all DECIMAL types are created equal and the OP would have to specify a DECIMAL type that guaranteed fixed-point precision.

Comment: And since you're new to StackOverflow, please don't forget to "Accept" (click the check mark) when you're happy with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically data values are stored in a database as numerical values, and the formatting is applied later.

In the case of currency, because you want a precise 2 decimal point value (Euro amounts typically are in whole Euros and 1/100 of a Euro amounts), you will need to select a database field type that limits the number of decimal points to 2.  The exact field type to use depends on the database you're using.